# Producing density map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector-grid, maps, density

I have placed a grid onto an open source Ordnance Survey map that corresponds to Ordnance Survey Eastings and Northings. I have a value for each grid square between zero and 30.

How do I use these values to produce a density map with 4 categories in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 4):

You want the ["Graduated" symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_attribute_data.html#graduated-symbols) option.

Just choose the column the has the values and choose 4 classes.

[image]

Comment: Just a small remark: if grids are *not* the same size you need some normalization, e.g. `"value" / $area`, in case if they are the same size simply use absolute values.